# Build message: Cannot open include file: 'msoledbsql.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-c++-6

My project can't finish build process because I constantly have this error during Visual Studio build: *Cannot open include file: 'msoledbsql.h': No such file or directory*

I have 'msoledbsql.h' file included in one of the header files.

Does anyone know the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long research of this issue I found that I've missing msoledbsql.h file on my machine.
The solution for this is to install Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server. We can find the driver on official Microsoft site [Microsoft OLD DB Driver for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and choose the one suitable for your system architecture (x64 or x86).

Very important thing during the installation process is to select both options

- OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server
- OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server SDK

[image: OLE DB Driver installation]

That should solve the issue.